# Calling a function immediately before main

Tags: c++, function, callback, program-entry-point

Is is possible to register a function to be run *immediately* before `main` is entered? I know that all global objects are created before entering `main`, so I could put the code in the constructor of a global object, but that does not guarantee any particular order. What I would like to do is put some registration code into the constructor, but alas, I don't know what to put there :) I guess this is highly system-specific?

Comment: Can you put the code "to be run immediately before `main` is entered" into `main()` then create a second function, `the_real_main()` that is called from there?  Maybe that is cheating.

Comment: The statment: <quote>does not guarantee any particular order</quote> is overally general and thus not quite correct. The order of construction with a compilation unit is well defined as the order of declaration. It is just the order between compilation units is not well defined (as it depends on the linker).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this function that cannot be done as the first function called in `main`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using `gcc`, you can use the `constructor` attribute on a function to have it called before `main` (see the [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) for more details).

> `constructor`
>
> `destructor`
>
> The `constructor` attribute causes the function to be called automatically before execution enters `main ()`. Similarly, the `destructor` attribute causes the function to be called automatically after `main ()` has completed or `exit ()` has been called. Functions with these attributes are useful for initializing data that will be used implicitly during the execution of the program.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is exactly what you want... But it should do the job.

```
int main() {
  static int foo = registerSomething();
}
```

It's better to explicitly calls such registration functions, either in main or on first access (but first access init could pose issues if you're multithreaded).

Comment: This isn't much different from just using `registerSomething()` without a static variable.

Comment: No, but it could (with some coercion) be said to logically execute before code in main :)

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing here but:

1. You want to register something in a different compilation unit
2. You ran into a problem with the registration because the global variables in which you're saving registrations were not yet constructed.

C++ defines that a function-static is initialized sometime before it is first accessed, so you can work around it in the way shown below.

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> RegistrationCache;

RegistrationCache& get_string_map()
{
    static RegistrationCache cache;
    return cache;
}

class Registration
{
    Registration(std::string name, std::string value)
    {
        get_string_map()[name] = value;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

### Goal

*Let's say you want the following:*

```
STATIC_EXECUTE {
  printf("This probably prints first"\n");
}

STATIC_EXECUTE {
  printf("But order isn't guaranteed in the language spec, IIRC"\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("This definitely prints last. Buh Bye.\n");
}
```

### Implementation

*C++ version - static variable + constructor:*

```
// This is some crazy magic that produces __StaticExecute__247
// Vanilla interpolation of __StaticExecute__##__LINE__ would produce __StaticExecute____LINE__
// I still can't figure out why it works, but it has to do with macro resolution ordering
// If you already have Boost, you can omit this part
#define BOOST_PP_CAT(a, b) BOOST_PP_CAT_I(a, b)
#define BOOST_PP_CAT_I(a, b) BOOST_PP_CAT_II(~, a ## b)
#define BOOST_PP_CAT_II(p, res) res

// This avoids repeating the BOOST_PP_CAT 5X
#define STATIC_EXECUTE \
  STATIC_EXECUTE_I(BOOST_PP_CAT(__StaticExecute__, __LINE__))

// This is the meat, a static instance of a class whose constructor runs your code
#define STATIC_EXECUTE_I(uniq_name)               \
static struct uniq_name {                         \
  uniq_name();                                    \
} BOOST_PP_CAT(uniq_name, __var);                 \
uniq_name::uniq_name()  // followed by { ... }
```

*C version - static variable + function*

```
// ... 

// The meat: a static variable initialized from a function call
#define STATIC_EXECUTE_I(uniq_name)            \
static void uniq_name ();                      \
static int BOOST_PP_CAT(uniq_name, __var) =    \
  (uniq_name(), 0);                            \
static void uniq_name()                        // followed by { ... }
```

### Notes

- IMHO, the C++ version is slightly more elegant. In-theory, it consumes slightly less space.  Otherwise, potato, po-tat-oh.
- Caveat: I haven't tested the "C" version on a proper C-only compiler.  Fingers crossed; post a note if it doesn't work.
- Caveat: Compiler portability in general is a tricky thing.  I wouldn't be shocked if there's a bug on some other compiler.
- The BOOST_PP_CAT code is stolen from [boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp).  I simplified the implementation, and in the process *may* have compromised portability.  If it doesn't work, try the original (more verbose) implementation, and post a comment below.  Or, if you are already using Boost, you can just use their version.
- If you are trying to understand the Boost magic, note that (at least for me, and in this scenario), the following also seems to work:

```
    #define BOOST_PP_CAT(a, b) BOOST_PP_CAT_I(a, b)
    #define BOOST_PP_CAT_I(a, b) a ## b
```

Comment: oops.  My first attempt is broken.  __StaticExecute__##__LINE__ turns into __StaticExecute____LINE__, NOT into __StaticExecute__247 like I expected.  Fixing it with some crazy magic stolen from Boost.