# 'Binding' Function Pointers on Load

Tags: c, function, function-pointers

So I've been tinkering around with object orientism in C by making a simple little stack using a 'class' struct and a `typedef`'d 'instance' struct. The class struct is simply full of function pointers that operate on pointers to instance structs. When I first went about it, I said to myself "I'll just bind the pointers when I initialize the instance struct!" You might guess that this didn't work, since my initialization function was actually a pointer that still had not been assigned a value yet.

(it's currently almost 5AM - closer to wakeup time than bedtime)

So, I am asking if there is any way to effectively bind the function pointers of the at runtime such that I don't need to explicitly call a function that binds them - I was thinking maybe some sort of counterpart to [`atexit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atexit/).

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/q/5222008/365188 OR http://stackoverflow.com/q/4880966/365188 is what you are looking for

Comment: The GCC thing works *great* for me, but it's not portable. The second link you provided is *definitely* not portable XD (from what I can tell)

Comment: Who can't you just declare the "class" struct as a static object initialized with the correct function pointers?

Comment: @vermiculus: look at this answer for a portable solution! Probably the only one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 'class' struct is always the same, you can initialise it statically:

```
void do_x_to_instance(instance *);
struct class_type {
    void (*do_x)(instance *);
    ...
} myclass = {
    &do_x_to_instance,
    ...
};
```

This is how the Python C API works to define extension types, for example.

Comment: Would I still be able to do this even if the functions haven't been defined yet?

Comment: @vermiculus yes, as long as the function has been declared at that point you can take a function pointer to it; the linker will ensure that the function pointer takes the correct value.